# Checking if a file exists before continuing [Obj-C]

Tags: objective-c, filesystems, while-loop, nsfilemanager

currently here is my code

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

BOOL receiptExists = NO;
BOOL didLog = NO;

while (!receiptExists) {

    receiptExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:PATH];

    if (!didLog) {
        NSLog(@"[NOTICE]: Waiting for the file to appear...\n");
        didLog = YES;
    }
}
// rest of the code
```

This while loop consumes a lot of resources and I'm sure there is a better obj-c implementation. Any thought ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the kqueue/kevent system, or FSEvents.

Using this, you can be notified of changes, instead of polling for them.

If you'd like an Objective-C abstraction of these, you may want to try [UKKQueue](http://zathras.de/programming/cocoa/UKKQueue.zip/) or [SCEvent](http://stuconnolly.com/blog/fsevents-objectivec-wrapper/).

Comment: Actually, FSEvents is separate from kqueue and has its own kernel support.